# Git bash (mIntty) roll back to original cygwin's bash

Tags: git, bash, cygwin

I installed git bash and chose option to replace PATHes so that git runs instead of cygwin's bash. Now i'm trying to get back to cygwin, so i reinstalled cygwin and when i run bash console directly from cygwin folder it runs ok, but not in mintty console, if i run mintty it fails to execute bash commands like *ls* saying that it's unknown command. I think that git somehow replaced smth in my path. I tried to remove pathes which contains 'git' from my windows PATH variable, but it still doesn't work. Any suggestions how to make mintty run with cygwin's bash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when running mintty i forgot to tell it run bash with option "-", so `mintty -` works fine.